# Parsec error - try doesn't seem to work

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm currently using the [Text.Parsec.Expr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Expr.html) module to parse a subset of a scripting language.

Basically, there are two kinds of commands in this language: Assignment of the form `$var = expr` and a Command of the form `$var = $array[$index]` - there are of course other commands, but this suffices to explain my problem.

I've created a type `Command`, to represent this, along with corresponding parsers, where `expr` for the assignment is handled by Parsec's `buildExpressionParser`.

Now, the problem. First the parsing code:

```
main = case parse p "" "$c = $a[$b]" of
          Left err -> putStrLn . show $ err
          Right r  -> putStrLn . show $ r
    where p = (try assignment <|> command) <* eof -- (1)
```

The whole code (50 lines) is pasted here: [Link](http://pastebin.com/3sB393Cy) (should compile if you've parsec installed)

The problem is, that parsing fails, since `assignment` doesn't successfully parse, even though there is a `try` before. Reversing the parsing order (`try command <|> assignment`) solves the problem, but is not possible in my case.

Of course I tried to locate the problem further and it appears to me, that the problem is the expression parser (build by `buildExpressionParser`), since parsing succeeds if I say `expr = fail ""`. However I can't find anything in the Parsec sources that would explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You parser fails because in fact `assigment` **does** succeeds here consuming `$c = $a` (try it with plain `where p = assignment`). Then there is supposed to be `eof` (or the rest of `expr` from `assigment`) hence the error. It seems that the beggining of your 'command' is identical to your 'assignment' in the case when 'assignment''s argument is just a `var` (like `$c = $a`).
Not sure why you can't reverse `command` and `assignment` but another way to make this particular example work would be:

```
main = case parse p "" "$c = $a[$b]" of
      Left err -> putStrLn . show $ err
      Right r  -> putStrLn . show $ r
   where p = try (assignment <* eof) <|> (command <* eof)
```